# "three times as much as" vs. "three times more"

Tags: comparative-constructions

*1. She earns three times as much as I.*

*2. She earns three times more than I.*

Are these two sentences grammatically correct?

Comment: Can't mark it as a duplicate as it's on another stack exchange, but there is an answer here http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7894/x-times-as-many-as-or-x-times-more-than

Comment: @GrahamNicol this is not a duplicate question on ELL.

Comment: As I said, it's on a different stack exchange (English Language & Usage), but it answers the same question.

Comment: The only reason the phrases differ is because you use *much* when talking about money and *many* when talking about sweets. The principle is still the same.

Answer (score 4):

n times as much definitely differs from n times more. Try making them equivalent when buying or selling a house, in computer code, or in a court of law and you'll be wrong every time. You'd better hope that the pharmacist preparing your meds understands the difference.

If you think they are the same, try the reverse and write a given math statement as English. Problem 1.: write "3n + n = x."    answer, 3 times n plus (more than) n is x.
Problem 2.: write "3n = x."                 answer, 3 times n is x.

This is NOT a case where a majority can agree and make the two equivalent. If you have no way to express exactly what you mean the statements are useless. The problem is not with an ambiguity in the English language.  I've had hundreds of student ask me what they will ever use math for, and here you have the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I disagree with Usernew. I interpret both to mean that if you take home £1000 per month, "she" takes home £3000 (for simplicity, ignoring tax)

While "as much as" does mean "the same quantity as" when used alone:

> I love you **as much as** you love me.
>   *These two people have equal amounts of love*

In your example it is being modified by the "three times"

```
She earns      three     times     as much as     I.  
Her income  =    3         x          (1x)        "Your income"
```

---

Both options for **as much as** / **more than** are fine. However I would change the end of the sentence slightly:

> She earns three times as much as / more than **me**.

or

> She earns three times as much as / more than **I do**.

---

From your comment on another answer:

> My wife and I work the same hours but I earn twice as much.

This is grammatical and means that if your wife brings home £1000 per month, you bring home £2000

Comment: suppose she used to earn $50 per day while you used to ear $150 per day, but now her income increased, and she earn three times more than what she earned before. You would not say, "she used to earn $50, and now she earns three times as much I earn"?

Comment: No. In that case, either you mean "She earns three times more than she used to" or "She now earns as much as me" or you mean that she now earns `$150x3=$450`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to JamesWebster for correcting the **big** mistake.

As far as I can tell, ***She earns as much as I*** means that **you both earn the same amount of money**.

---

I recommend reading [this news article published on The Guardian.](http://www.theguardian.com/money/2014/sep/15/trainee-earning-the-same-as-me)

---

"As much as" means **as same quantity as** as provided by [thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/as+much+as)

> She earns three times more than I.

It means that she earns 3x of what you earn.

So, if you earn $100, she earns $400.

> She earns three times as much as I.

This means that if you have $100, she earns $300.

If you earn X dollars, "three times more than x" means `3x + x` -- "more than" means "add".

"Three times as much" means 3x.

[Yahooanswers](https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090914135554AAYz0h5)

[thegrammarexchange](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/2122987507)

Comment: Are you sure that my first sentence indicates that we both earn the same amount of money? I wanted to express in both sentences that she earns much more than I.

Comment: And what about this sentence? My wife and I work the same hours but I earn twice as much. It is without doubt grammatically OK.

Comment: @bart-leby Do check both the new answers. Sorry for misleading. PS - I am still a learner.

Comment: Your answer is better, but now it misquotes the OP. `An alternative to first one, without changing the meaning` now *does* change the meaning

Comment: @JamesWebster Sorry :"( forgot to delete that section. Edited it. Thanks again ;)

Comment: I reckon this is nearly worthy of an upvote now, but I still disagree with one point. `She earns three times more than I` actually means `HI = 3 x MI` rather than `HI = (3 x MI) + MI`. The sentences are identical in meaning.

Comment: @JamesWebster but it says *Three times* ***more***

Comment: I know, but English is strange. I've just ask my colleagues this. (All 4 native English speakers). We're all in agreement that no matter what the construction, if I earn £1000, she earns £3000.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30545/discussion-between-usernew-and-james-webster).