# Use of money three times as much as

Tags: usage

> You make three times as much money as I'm making!
>
> You make money that is three times as much  as I'm making!
>
> You make three money (((that is))) times as much  as I'm making!

Are all sentences correct especially third one? Can I say “ money three times as much as“ without using “ that is”?

Comment: There's something wrong with verb agreement here.  It should be "You make three times as much money as I make."

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/71474/three-times-as-much-as-vs-three-times-more

Comment: Heh. Isn't it weird that English includes the phrase "to make money" and is not referring to counterfeiting?